# consistency for array parameters

Tags: support, api

It would simplify the api and consumption there of if all parameters that accept multiple items used a common delimiter.

We have semicolon and space that I know of so far.

Eliminating space as a delimiter is not necessary, but adding semicolon as a valid delimiter would serve to provide a consistent api and should not break existing code as semicolon is not typically a search component.

Also, regardless of whether there is a change, declaration of the delimiter on 'list of' params would be helpful.

Comment: I would certainly like to see the semicolon be the only delimiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything that's not semi-colon delimited should be considered a bug.

Comment: good. see http://stackapps.com/questions/711/api-parameters-consolidated-observations for a few bugs

Comment: is this going to be fixed?