# API Parameters: Consolidated Observations

Tags: support, api, parameters

This wiki question is meant to be a central location for observations and suggestions in the interest of shaping the API meta data.

Perhaps items can be removed when accepted and resolved as suggested or <strike>stricken</strike> when rejected to avoid recurrence.

Other one-off questions could be merged into this central wiki.

A consolidate view of the API parameters can be seen using [param-exam](https://stackapps.com/questions/710/soapi-param-exam-a-flat-sortable-filterable-list-of-all-parameters-in-the-stack).

---

`order` parameter description is inconsistent.

They could be replaced with `How the current sort should be ordered.`

- /tags
- /users/{id}/tags
- /search
- /users
- /users/{id}

---

<strike>Tag list parameter delimiters vary between space, semi-colon and both, and are not documented.</strike>

The could be better served by accepting both space and semi-colon as delimiter and documenting them as such.

- /search - `tagged`, `nottagged` -- semi-colon delimited
- /questions, /questions/unanswered -- `tagged` - space delimited

---

<strike>`sort` parameter is inconsistent with the rest of the api and contain incorrect and redundant enumerations.</strike>

They could be replaced with `How a collection should be sorted.`

- /search
- /users
- /users/{id}

---

<strike>`min` and `max` parameters are incorrectly typed as date.</strike>

They could be better typed as `string`.

- /answers/{id}
- /answers/{id}/comments
- /comments/{id}
- /posts/{id}/comments
- /questions
- /questions/{id}
- /questions/{id}/answers
- /questions/{id}/comments
- /questions/tagged/{tags}
- /questions/unanswered
- /search
- /users/{id}/answers
- /users/{id}/comments
- /users/{id}/comments/{toid}
- /users/{id}/favorites
- /users/{id}/mentioned
- /users/{id}/questions

---

`fromdate` and `todate` parameters are inconsistent with the rest of the api.

They could be better described as `Unix timestamp of the minimum creation date on a returned item.` and `Unix timestamp of the maximum creation date on a returned item.` respectively.

- /revisions/{id}
- /revisions/{id}/{revisionguid}

---

`page` parameter name is inconsistent with the rest of the API.

It could be better described as `The pagination offset for the current collection. Affected by the specified pagesize.`

- /questions/{id}/timeline

---